# Evaluating von-Mangoldt sum of the form $\sum_{1\leq x\leq m} \sum_{1\leq y\leq n}\Lambda(x)\Lambda(y)$, for $m\neq n$

Tags: analytic-number-theory, arithmetic-functions

I am unable to understand this since several months.

Let $Λ$ be the [von-Mangoldt function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Mangoldt_function).
Then we know the following: $\sum_{1\leq x\leq n}\Lambda(x)^{2}\sim n \log n$.

Then for $m\neq n$ and $x\neq y $ is the following true?\begin{equation}
 \sum_{1\leq x\leq m} \sum_{1\leq y\leq n}\Lambda(x)\Lambda(y) \sim m n.
\end{equation}

Comment: The condition $x\neq y$ does not make much sense. If you do not have that restriction, this is just a simple consequence of the prime number theorem, since your expression is $\psi(m) \psi(n)$ where $\psi$ is the Chebyshev function.

Comment: @Gary, since, $\sum_{1\leq x\leq y\leq n} \Lambda(x)\Lambda(y)\sim n^2$, for $x\neq y$,  I thought I may write like this: $\sum_{1\leq x\leq m} \sum_{1\leq y\leq n}\Lambda(x)\Lambda(y)$

Comment: $\psi(m)\psi(n) \sim mn$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your sum is
\begin{align*}
& \left( {\sum\limits_{1 \le x \le m} {\Lambda (x)} } \right)\left( {\sum\limits_{1 \le y \le n} {\Lambda (y)} } \right) - \sum\limits_{1 \le z \le k} {\Lambda ^2 (z)} \\ & = (m + o(m))(n + o(n)) - k\log k+o(k\log k)
\\ & = mn + o(mn) - k\log k+o(k\log k) =mn+o(mn),
\end{align*}
where $k=\min(m,n)$.

Comment: thank you very much indeed ; but how did you get that expression? I m much new to analytic number theory..

Comment: thank you got it